# SQL radius search

Tags: sql, sql-server, geospatial

Suppose I have a polygon shaped geographical area made up of 5 lat/lon points such as : -

```
51.314869, -0.497125
51.255586, 0.237066
51.684476, 0.244771
51.725210, -0.514339
51.314869, -0.497125
```

I then do a radius search from a single point (e.g. 51.728215, -1.209971) of 30 miles. I want to be able to find out if that radius search encompasses any or all of that polygon area.

I'm aware that there is a geography data type available in SQL Server and if needed the data can be changed to this if it makes solving it easier

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you provide the code that  you have already written?

Comment: I haven't tried anything so far because I don't really know what to do. If it was checking the distance between 2 points then no problem, but I've never done anything like this before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
declare @g geography =
    geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((
        51.314869 -0.497125 ,
        51.255586 0.237066  ,
        51.684476 0.244771  ,
        51.725210 -0.514339 ,
        51.314869 -0.497125 
    ))', 4326);

set @g=@g.ReorientObject();

declare @p geography =
    --geography::Point(-0.497125, 51.314869, 4326);
    geography::STPointFromText('POINT(51.314869 -0.497125)', 4326);

select @g.STIntersects(@p.STBuffer(48280.3))
```

By way of explanation, I'm using the geography datatype like your intuitions said should be possible. I first construct a polygon that represents your area. The syntax for the actual polygon is called WKT (i.e. well-known text) and is a standard in geospatial.

The next step is I have to reorient your object. Why? A gotcha with geographic polygons is that they can define either the area interior to the boundary or exterior to it depending on the order in which the points are defined. In this case, the order that you specified them in defined the exterior of the area (i.e. the entire globe minus a very small quadrilateral), so I made an assumption that you wanted the interior of that area for consideration (which it turns out will is necessary as you'll see below).

Next, I construct a point. I chose one of the corners of your polygon out of convenience. Note, I've provided two ways to do it. I personally prefer to use the `Point()` method, but you can use WKT to do it too!

Lastly, I test for an intersection between your polygon (`@g`) and a disk centered on the point that has a radius of 30 miles (or 48280.3 meters). The test returns a boolean. Speaking to the assumption on the point ordering in the polygon, if you define the points in the wrong order, the intersection test will return true for things that aren't even close to your polygon (since it defines almost all of the globe). On first glance, you'd think that you could just reverse the test (i.e. a logical negation of the `STIntersects()` test), but I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader why that's not the correct thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize the search by computing a bounding box by taking the min and max of lat/lon. Then you can search the DB by comparing with the min/max lat/long. Finally, you can filter the remaining data by checking whether the lat/lon is inside the polygon. This is not that difficult to do if your polygon is convex. You have to break it down into triangles, and check whether the lat/lon is inside one of them.